# Is there anyway to make onclick's work when the content is updating?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, onclick

Here's the problem: I have an interface with some stats, the stats are changing fast, maybe every 500ms, on this interface, there are onclick's too, it is very convenient for me to render everything at once, the project isn't refined enough to practically separate stats from the interactive elements

The technical problem: Click's/onclick's miss if the content is updating, they miss 50% of the time for the above scenario

Here's a codepen that demonstrates this issue: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkRBQB

```js
clicks=0;
setInterval(function(){
  $("#content").html("<div onclick='clicks++'>Try to click this ...</div>")
  $("#clicks").html(clicks);
},135);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
</div>
Clicks <span id="clicks">0</span>
```

Comment: What about attaching the event handler to the body element and then filtering out the other elements by using an appropriate selector as the second parameter to the .on() function?

Comment: Hmm, can you provide a codepen snippet that demonstrates the idea? At first sight, it seemed more complex than an "isolated updates" based solution, rather than "top-level updates"